# How do i add LogCat into "Output" Visual Studio Code?

Tags: android, react-native, logging, visual-studio-code, output

at Visual Studio Code, i have an extension called ***React Native Tools***

[image: React Native Tools]

and after using `React Native: Run Android on Device` i have a Logcat in **Output** like this:

[image: LogCat]

My question is how can i create Logcat into **Output** tab Manually? in case i'm not used `React Native: Run Android on Device`.

the command of Logcat itself is `adb -s 192.168.137.52:5556 logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`